# Access dynamic control from class in a thread

Tags: c#, forms, interface, controls, invoke

I'm working on a small project which deals with polling devices to check states of I/O controls. I had implemented a small project dealing with a particular device, but have decided that i would like to eventually implement different devices, and so have moved over to an class : interface approach. This has caused a few problems however, since i moved a lot of code around.

Before i moved the code around and such, i was accessing dynamic form controls by using a delegate as such;

```
 if (result != null)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    txtOutput1.Text = (result[4] == 0x00 ? "HIGH" : "LOW"); // runs on UI thread

                    if (result[4] == 0x00)
                    {
                        this.Controls["btn" + buttonNumber].BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Controls["btn" + buttonNumber].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }


                });

            }
```

This worked fine until i moved certain methods to a new class which inherits from an interface. I don't want to just set the dynamic buttons to public, and i'm not sure i can create get;set; for dynamic buttons, considering theres lots of them and are created on startup. Another problem is the this.invoke" command. I believe the invoke command doesn't work unless it's placed on a form...and now it's been moved to a class, so i need to look at another way of doing this.

Does anyone have any ideas as to where i should be heading with this?

EDIT 1:

The program is designed as a monitoring system for hardware devices that handle inputs/outputs. using these i can check if, for example, a door alarm has been triggered and such. The program itself in terms of forms / design is very simple. Currently i have a single form, which generates buttons based on information in a database, for example if there are 10 devices configured, there are 10 buttons. each of these shows green / red dependant on the hardware state.

My main form triggers a thread for each device which monitors it, but because i wished to have multiple types of device i moved them to different classes and an interface which handles all of the common methods. Currently i have a device class, which implements an interface. With regards to this question, i need to now access an instance of the single main form from which i am updating, rather than creating a new instance, so that i can use the new method i created when i moved said logic into the form itself.

EDIT 2:

```
    IdeviceInterface bfdeviceimp = new bf2300deviceimp();
   // some other declarations and initialize components

 private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateUI();
    }

    public void updateUI()
    {

        DBConnector mDBConnector = new DBConnector();
        int count = mDBConnector.Count() - 1;
        DataTable dataTable = mDBConnector.Select("SELECT * FROM devices");


        int x = 12;
        int y = 65;
        for (int i = 0; i <= count && i < 25; i++)
        {

            Button btnAdd = new Button();
            btnAdd.Text = dataTable.Rows[i]["deviceDescription"].ToString();
            btnAdd.Location = new Point(x, y);
            btnAdd.Tag = i;
            btnAdd.Name = "btn" + i.ToString();
            btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Green;
            var temp = i + 1;
            this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);

            this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                int index = temp;
                generalMethods.generatePopup(sender, e, index);
            };

            string address = dataTable.Rows[i]["deviceIP"].ToString();
            int port = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i]["devicePort"].ToString());


            ThreadStart workerThread = delegate { start(address, port, i); };
            new Thread(workerThread).Start();

            x = (x + 75);
            if (i != 0 && (i % 5) == 0)
            {
                x = 12;
                y = y + 30;
            }
            if (i == 25)
            {
                Button btnPreviousPage = new Button();
                btnPreviousPage.Text = "<";
                btnPreviousPage.Location = new Point(150, 350);
                btnPreviousPage.Tag = "left";
                this.Controls.Add(btnPreviousPage);

                Button btnNextPage = new Button();
                btnNextPage.Text = ">";
                btnNextPage.Location = new Point(225, 350);
                btnNextPage.Tag = "right";
                this.Controls.Add(btnNextPage);
            }
        }
    }
    public void start(string address, int port, int i)
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);


            timer.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) { timerElapsed(sender, e, address, port, i); };
        }
        timer.Enabled = true;
        // MessageBox.Show("Thread " + i + " Started.");
    }
    public void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, string address, int port, int i)
    {
        bfdeviceimp.newconnect(address, port, i);
    }
```

and then finally my device class:

```
   class bf2300deviceimp : IdeviceInterface
{
   public void newconnect(string address, int port, int buttonNumber)
    {
        //send data
        byte[] bData = new byte[71];
        bData[0] = 240;
        bData[1] = 240;
        bData[2] = 0;
        bData[3] = 1;
        bData[68] = 240;
        bData[69] = 240;
        bData[70] = this.newCalculateCheckSum(bData);


        try
        {
            byte[] result = this.newSendCommandResult(address, port, bData, 72);

           //form1.setAlarmColour(result, buttonNumber);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Where would you suggest i put the statechanged handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use an events-based approach for solving this problem, as is often the case when it comes to passing information between forms.  Each of your devices should have a custom event that they define which is fired when the state of that device changes.  The event should probably just be defined in the interface for interacting with that device.  The form, when it creates the various device classes should subscribe to the event and in the event handler it should update the button/textbox appropriately.

This might be a fair bit to take in if you're not used to this style of programming.  Feel free to ask for more details in the comments and I can elaborate on why I did something the way I did or what it actually does.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //not sure if this is on initialization or in a button click event handler or wherever.
    IDevice device = new SomeDevice();
    device.StatusChanged += GetHandlerForDevice(1);
    device.DoStuff();

    IDevice device2 = new SomeDevice(); //could be another class that implements IDevice
    device.StatusChanged += GetHandlerForDevice(2);
    device.DoStuff();
}

/// <summary>
/// The handlers for device status changed only vary based on the button number for each one.
/// This method takes a button number and returns an event handler that uses that button number.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="buttonNumber"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs> GetHandlerForDevice(int buttonNumber)
{
    //use currying so that the event handler which doesn't have an appropriate signature
    //can be attached to the status changed event.
    return (sender, args) => device_StatusChanged(sender, args, buttonNumber);
}

private void device_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs args, int buttonNumber)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        txtOutput1.Text = (args.CurrentStatus == IDevice.Status.Green ? "HIGH" : "LOW"); // runs on UI thread

        if (args.CurrentStatus == IDevice.Status.Green)
        {
            this.Controls["btn" + buttonNumber].BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Controls["btn" + buttonNumber].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }


    });
}



public interface IDevice
{
    event EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged;
    Status CurrentStatus { get; }


    public enum Status
    {
        Green,
        Red
    }

    void DoStuff();
    // rest of interface ...
}

public class StatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public IDevice.Status CurrentStatus { get; set; }
    //can add additional info to pass from an IDevice to a form if needed.
}

public class SomeDevice : IDevice
{
    public event EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged;

    private IDevice.Status _currentStatus;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current status of the device this object represents.
    /// When set (privately) it fires the StatusChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    public IDevice.Status CurrentStatus
    {
        get { return _currentStatus; }
        private set
        {
            _currentStatus = value;
            if (StatusChanged != null)
            {
                StatusChangedEventArgs args = new StatusChangedEventArgs();
                args.CurrentStatus = value;
                StatusChanged(this, args);
            }
        }
    }


    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //... do stuff
        CurrentStatus = IDevice.Status.Green; //will fire status changed event
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm assuming i'd have to create a new instance of the form in order to access the method from the class? would that cause any issues?

Comment: If you don't have any instance of the form then what textbox/button are you planning to update?  You want to get the instance of whatever form you want to change.  Eventually, no matter what you try to do, you'll need to do that.

Comment: sorry, my comment probably made no sense, what i meant was. does something like;

               BF2300 form1 = new BF2300();
               form1.setAlarmColour(result, buttonNumber);

create a new instance of the form, or get the current one i wish to update?

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter That creates a new form.  Since we don't know anything about how your program is structures I can't intelligently tell you how you should appropriately access an instance of the form.

Comment: thanks anyway, solved my problem pretty much, just need to do a little reading on the form access, but as far as my initial question goes, solved.

Comment: If you post some more details (either here or in a new question) about the layout of your program at a higher level (what the whole thing does, what classes create/use other classes, etc.) then I could provide a more detailed and specific answer.

Comment: wow, this looks daunting. with regards to the current project though, i use events and such, literally EVERYTHING works apart from changing these button colours, which happens in the method we earlier used that i moved to the form.. would you still suggest looking into moving more towards your answer?

Comment: Well, a good half of my answer is just shelling out code that I'm sure you already have just so that my answer would be complete.  `device_StatusChanged` is just a small modification of the code in your OP.  The rest of the Form code is just creating Devices (I'm sure you're already doing that) and attaching the event.  On the device side, you'll just need to add an `event` to the interface and fire that event when the status changes.  Most of the rest of that stuff isn't required to make this work, it's just things that make it nicer.  i.e. the `enum` and `CurrentStatus` aren't *required*.

Comment: i'm going to have a look at implementing some of this in there. i think i only really need to add the custom event handler, and that's about it really. will it matter that i'm creating dynamically or that each of the device polluing is done in it's own thread?

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter I wrote this assuming that both of those things were true, so it should be just fine.

Comment: the way i'm doing it, actually doesn't create new devices the way you've done, i've created an instance of the interface / device, and then created a new thread containing this for each different device. does this make sense? check my edit for some code. edit: code updated

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter Reviewing your edit it appears to be more or less what I would have expected.  Your Device class doesn't show what the instance fields are, so I can't see what you're sharing between the buttons.  If it's something that every single device shares then you could make it static; if not, then have some connection that you create outside the loop and pass to each of the 25 device objects so that they can share whatever it is that you need them to share.  It's worthwhile to have a Device object that corresponds to each button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11700/discussion-between-shane-shamus-coulter-and-servy)

Comment: i'm having some trouble with the status declaration in the interface, i'm getting... 'status': interfaces cannot declare types, at; Status CurrentStatus { get; }


        public enum Status
        {
            Green,
            Red
        }

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter Yeah, I realized that myself.  Just remove the declaration of the enumeration outside of the interface; make it a top level object, and then adjust how you access it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Move all the logic inside a method in the form and use it externally.

Answer (score 0):

In your form create a property

```
public SynchronizationContext SyncContext { get; set;}
```

In form constructor add:

```
this.SyncContext = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Make interface:

```
public Interface IChangeClient 
{
    void Process(<some_type> result); // place your logic here
}
```

(or somethng like that) and implement it in your Form to change your buttons and text.

Extend your original interface to use (maybe as a parameter) `SynchronizationContext` and `IBackgroundChangeClient`.

And than your code would look like this:

```
if (result != null)
{
    oSyncContext.Post(new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(
            delegate(object state)
            {
                IBackgroundChangeClient client = (state as object[])[0] as IBackgroundChangeClient
                //i dont konw the type of this
                var innerResult= (state as object[])[1];
                client.Process(innerResult);
            }), new object[] { oBackgroundChangeClient, result[4]});

}
```

Comment: The textbox is also a part of the same form.  Pretty much the entire code snippet posted is just a UI change.  The business logic is all in setting the variables (not shown).  I don't see why you wouldn't want the entire snippet shown moved into the Form.

Comment: Why do you consider it the responsibility of the caller to move everything to the UI thread?  Why not just keep that logic in the form's method.  It's easier if you do, and in my mind it makes since for a UI component to properly manage that itself.